# C#: Run process and then kill it using a button

Tags: c#, executable, kill

I hope that you can help me with this one, my C# is very rusty.

I'm running an executable when the form loads.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo exe = new ProcessStartInfo();
        exe.Arguments = "arguments";
        exe.FileName = "file.exe";
        Process.Start(exe);
    }
```

And I would like to kill that process using a button, but I don't know how to achieve that.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Would process achieve what you want?http://www.dotnetperls.com/kill

Comment: If you are also the author of the "other" process you might want to consider user a synchronization object, e.g. a named [mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx), to communicate a stop request. The second process can have a thread wait on the event and perform any appropriate actions before exiting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Process.Start` returns an object of type `Process`. You can save it into variable, then use the method `Kill`, which `Immediately stops the associated process` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

For example declare a field at `Form1` level:

```
class Form1
{
    private Process process;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //running notepad as an example
        process = Process.Start("notepad"); 
    }

    //and then at button handler kill that process
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //consider adding check for null
        process.Kill();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working. However, is there any way to kill the process if the application is closed forcefully?

Answer (score 3):

You should call [Process.CloseMainWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which performs an orderly termination of the process and closes all windows.  As opposed to [Process.Kill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which causes abnormal termination.  CloseMainWindow is preferable for applications with a user interface.

```
process =  Process.Start(exe);//in form load set field

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   process.CloseMainWindow();
}
```

The [remarks on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) reveals important information regarding the asynchronous behavior and other relevant details.

> Kill forces a termination of the process, while CloseMainWindow only
>   requests a termination. When a process with a graphical interface is
>   executing, its message loop is in a wait state. The message loop
>   executes every time a Windows message is sent to the process by the
>   operating system. Calling CloseMainWindow sends a request to close to
>   the main window, which, in a well-formed application, closes child
>   windows and revokes all running message loops for the application. The
>   request to exit the process by calling CloseMainWindow does not force
>   the application to quit. The application can ask for user verification
>   before quitting, or it can refuse to quit. To force the application to
>   quit, use the Kill method. The behavior of CloseMainWindow is
>   identical to that of a user closing an application's main window using
>   the system menu. Therefore, the request to exit the process by closing
>   the main window does not force the application to quit immediately.

etc...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
try
{
Process [] proc Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
proc[0].Kill();
}
```